# How to customize kibana field datetime format to MMM YY format in table visualization

Tags: datetime-format, kibana-4

I am trying to create a simple table kibana visualization that summarizes data into monthly buckets for with row counts.  Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to customize this summary so the time perspective is represented as "MMM YY" format rather than the original timestamp format of the index.

[Kibana displays timestamp, but would like month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJp09.png)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to navigate to the kibana screen with list of all fields in your index (I think it's management)
Then look for the date field and press on the edit button, in the new screen that will open you can define the format.

Comment: The field is a datetimestamp field and there are other scenarios where we still need it to be a datetimestamp format for other visualizations.  But for that visualization we need to clean it up with the proper format.